# Float left for span and div together is not working the way I want to

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a coming soon template and what im trying to reach with my code is here in this photo.

[image]

but what im getting in my code is this

[image]

My HTML code and CSS code is down below:

```css
.days {
  font-size: 180px;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
}
.smalltext {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="clockdiv">
  <li>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    <span class="days"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Question is how can I float both of them to left like the design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it  is not a good idea to use floats.

However, the classical answer to your issue would be to use a **clear** on the second element:

```css
.days {
  font-size: 180px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.smalltext {
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="smalltext">Days</div>
<span class="days">135</span>
```

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 5):

Simple: Remove `float` altogether.

I believe you've slightly overthought this. `float` specifically tells elements to position themselves adjacently, whereas your desired appearance seems to be the exact opposite.

Block elements like `<div>` will naturally appear atop one another and left-aligned unless instructed otherwise, so by removing the `float: left;` from both elements, you should be able to achieve your desired look.

Additionally, just to satiate my own curiosity... I'm assuming there's a reason you're using `<ul>` and `<li>` list elements for this (which doesn't seem to be a list of any sort)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use left margin to days class or you dont's need to use float left just use to div and margin to days div.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider using "div" elements to wrap and align the text:

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper1">Days</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">136</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper1 {
  position:    relative;
  width:       100%;
  text-align:  left;
  font-size:   25px;
  font-family: Oswald;
}

.wrapper2 {
  position:    relative;
  width:       100%;
  text-align:  left;
  font-size:   180px;
  font-family: Oswald;
}

.wrapper2 p {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
```